# Can't get prop to update in vue.js component

Tags: vue.js

I have been trying for hours to get this to work. I need to update a boolean that is passed to a child component, but it always returns `false`.

I have created the variable with a default value `false` here.

`someApp.js`

```
let someApp = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        // ... irrelevent data
        showDialogRepair: false
    },
```

I also have the following method defined in `someApp.js`:

```
add_repair: function () {
           this.showDialogRepair = true
            console.log(this.showDialogRepair)
        },
```

I'm using another component `some-list` inside of `someApp` and passing my `showDialogRepair` variable as a prop called `showData`:

```
<some-list
  ...
  :showData="showDialogRepair"
  ...
>
</some-list>
```

The variable `showDialogRepair` is updated by the `add_repair()` function and `console.log` returns `true`

Now inside `repair-list` I have registered my props:

```
Vue.component('some-list', {
    props: {
        ...
        showData: {type: Boolean}
    },
```

My data:

```
data: function () {
        return {
            ...
            showDialogRepair: this.showData
        }
    },
```

and finally the method I am calling from the child component `some-list`:

```
add_new_repair: function () {
            console.log(this.showData)
        },
```

Which is returning `false`

I have also tried to add a watcher in `watch:`

```
showDialogRepair: function (newVal, oldVal) {
            this.showDialogRepair = newVal;
        },
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `add_new_repair`? Parent? Child? How are you calling it? Please read [mcve]

Comment: `add_new_repair` is called in the child component. I am using a simple button with `@click` for right now just to log the results, but I need to trigger a `v-dialog` when `true`

Also trying to keep the example short because this is a very large app. I can't share the whole source either.

Comment: Shouldn't you be watching `this.showData` to update `showDialogRepair ` when it changes?

Comment: `showData: function (newVal, oldVal) {this.showDialogRepair = newVal;},`

Still returns false after I have called `add_repair()`

Oddly enough, if I switch the parent component initial value of `showDialogRepair` to `true` the value is still returning `false` after being passed to the child.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looks like the issue is with `:showData="showDialogRepair"` needing to be `:show-data="showDialogRepair"` due to constraints within HTML requiring "kebab-case" to pass the props. I'm used to ReactJS and got tasked with this Vue.js project, everything is so different.